# How can I find all people within N miles of a location (Entity Framework)

Tags: entity-framework, geocoding, nettopologysuite

I am trying to save a location for all users and then search for all users within N miles of a given location. I am storing all users in SQL Server and accessing the database via Entity Framework.

Based on Google search answers for this are all over the place. The most recent seems to be [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-types/spatial) but following it `System.Data.Spatial` is not found and `DbGeography` is unrecognized. I have added the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite`

Is there a working example of how to store and query this information?

Comment: Are you wanting to store the distance between each pair of users? Storage complexity = O(n²)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor No. For a given location I need to find all users within say 10 miles of that location.

Comment: This is not a storage problem. It is a calculation problem. You could do simple Pythagoras theorem to the two points. This gets tricky if the map is big, because the earth is not flat. However, it can be good enough for a city or state or maybe a country. But even then, it will have its problems: e.g. which is closer `A is 1 mile from B, but the route is 5 miles` Or A has a 2-mile straight  road to B`?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I think it's a storage & calculation problem. Storage question - what do I store this as and what package do I need to add for that class. Calculation question, how do I structure a query to get all user's within 5 miles of a point - as the crow flies.

This is all for short distances and so I assume I can just do within N miles of the desired point. Yes actual driving can be impacted by topology, traffic, etc. Not worth worrying about for my use.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these resources

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial?source=recommendations
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHslY5rrxD0&list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oX-DBuRG4u58ZTAJgBAeQ-t&index=16